# Table sorting causing duplication in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I have a table of data with sorting for each coloumn. When I keep on clicking the coloumn for sorting, the table itself is getting multiplied.

This is the code for setting session variables.

```
'click #coloumn_name' : function()
{
    var oldOrder = Session.get("sortOrder");
    var sortField = 'coloumn1';
    Session.set("sortField",sortField );
    if(oldOrder == 1)
    {
        var newOrder = -1;
        Session.set("sortOrder",newOrder );
    }
    else
    {
        var newOrder = 1;
        Session.set("sortOrder",newOrder );
    }
}
```

Here is the code for reading the session variables and fetching data from db.

```
Template.templatename.vname = function()
{
    var filter = {sort: {}};
    var sortField = Session.get('sortField');
    var sortOrder = Session.get('sortOrder');
    if(!sortField)
    {
        sortField = 'coloumn2';
    }
    if(!sortOrder)
    {
        sortOrder = 1;
    }   
    filter.sort[sortField] = sortOrder;
    return Groups.find({}, filter);     
}
```

Here is my template

```
  <template name="templatename">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <th>Group Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
       {{#each vname }}  
      <tr>
       <td> {{name}} </td>
       <td> {{status}} </td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
  </template>
```

This is the table before trying to sort.
[image]

```
This is the image after trying to sort
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Whats your template look like?

Comment: @Deve... I have added the template also to the question..